# NancyFX Error: Unable to locate view 'Int32' How do I fix this?

Tags: c#, nancy

I'm learning NancyFX and I have a simple route that returns an id that a user requests.  Here's the code:

```
using Nancy;

namespace NancyFXTutorial
{
    public class CarModule : NancyModule
    {
        public CarModule()
        {
            Get["/status"] = _ => "Hello World";

            Get["/car/{id}"] = parameters =>
            {
                int id = parameters.id;

                return Negotiate
                    .WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    .WithModel(id);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

When I request http://localhost/car/43234, I get an error message that says: `Nancy.RequestExecutionException: Oh noes! ---> Nancy.ViewEngines.ViewNotFoundException: Unable to locate view 'Int32'`

What does this mean?  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extension method you can chain onto `Negotiate` called `WithView` which lets you specify a view to use when the client requests an HTML response:

```
return Negotiate
                .WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                .WithModel(id)
                .WithView("YourView");
```

The view you indicate can use the model you pass into `WithModel`.